# Flash/ActionScript 3.0 How can I continually loop frames in same scene without going to next scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I continually loop frames with a 20 second pause in each frame from the same scene without going to the next scene? There are buttons for the other scenes in these frames. The below works well until I am at the last frame in scene one, then it goes to the next scene and plays. How can I make scene one a continually loop.

```
stop();

var timer:Timer = new Timer(20000,0);//<--
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    this.nextFrame();
    //or if you want to jump e.g 5 frames
    this.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame+5);
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, consider marking as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check and see if your next frame is going to be the last frame:

```
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    if(this.currentFrame + 1 <= this.totalFrame){ //if your desired destination is less than the total frames, then your safe to goto to the nextFrame - replace the +1 with however many frames you want to skip
        this.nextFrame();
    }else{ //if not, reset back to frame one (loop)
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think gotoAndPlay is needed to keep things going

Comment: @RST They are using a timer to advance the timeline